# Allowing a user to login even if the password is slightly off

Tags: encryption, authentication, passwords, login-script

I implemented the following login system:

A user can login if the password is slightly different (for example a character should be uppercase but is lowercase) if the following are to be respected:

- The IP of the login should match the previous IPs that the user had used to login before.
- The difference between the entered password should be minimal, therefore it does not allow the user to login if it contains more than 2/3 differences.
- Optional - Record the time that the user takes to write down the password and ensure that the user did not take too long.

What are your opinions about the security of such a system?

Comment: This should probably be moved to http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

## Don't do this

Unless this login script is nothing more than a toy, and will never see the light of a production environment, don't do this. Arguing against your points, here's why:

1. IPs change. And even if your user has a static IP, IPs can be spoofed
2. How are you calculating these differences? String comparison? You shouldn't be storing passwords as plain text. And hash comparisons should be exact, with no wiggle room.
3. What if I walk away from my computer while logging in? What if the user momentarily forgot? What if the user is really bad at typing, or is physically disabled and needs to take their time? Too many variable here, the login mechanism becomes needlessly complex, with no real payoff. If anything, a "too fast" limit might be smarter, to slow down brute forcing the password.